# ASP.NET MVC .Валидация на клиенте

Tags: c#, asp.net, валидация

Создал атрибуты для валидации данных модели.Однако валидация происходит на стороне сервера, на клиенте никак не работают.Как это исправить?

Один из атрибутов

```
public class GenderAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "Мужской" || value.ToString() == "Женский")
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

P.S. все скрипты для ненавязчивой валидации подключил

Comment: Код в вопросе - для серверной валидации.

Comment: @Igor можете, пожалуйста, указать ссылку на источник, где объясняется создание атрибутов для клиентской валидации.

Comment: Ко всему вышесказанному: if-else в данном случае -- моветон, можно и нужно просто написать return value != null && value.ToString()...  Кроме того, в данном случае строки стоит сравнивать без учета регистра и локали (StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), а еще лучше вообще не использовать строки для описания пола, для этого лучше подойдет bool или enum.

Comment: Вы написали алгоритм валидации на C#, но как по вашему JS код должен узнать, как валидировать форму? Лучше сделайте стандартными средствами на регулярках, используя RegularExpressionAttribute

Comment: Чтобы перенести Вашу кастомную логику валидации на клиент рантайм каким-то образом должен знать, как ваш C# преобразовать в JS, Вам надо реализовать интерфейс IClientValidatable. Посмотрите эту статью: https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation

Comment: @SerafimProzorov а какая разница там что-то другое использовать, html-код никто изменить не может.Значения пола уже заранее заданы, пользователю нужно просто выбрать один из элемента select

Comment: @PrimusSingularis я привел один из атрибутов.Не все из них можно просто заменить регулярками.

Comment: у вас не работает клиентская валидация вообще, даже стандартная на основе атрибутов валидации?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да, клиентская не работает, с серверной все нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того что бы клиентская валидация работала, сейчас я говорю о стандартной валидации на основе атрибутов модели, вам нужно специальным образом разметить модель.

```
public class Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1700,2000,ErrorMessage="Недопустимый год")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

[Тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/7.3.php) можно почитать более подробно про подключения валидаци.. Так же не забудьте подключить ненавязчивую валидацию в конфиге, а так же подключить сам скрипт ненавязчивой валидации.

Подключаем скрипт на страницу

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

в `Web.config`

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

Если вам нужна кастомная валидация на клиенте то смотрим https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/7.3.php , раздел *remote*.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за ответ, но с тем, что вы указали я уже знаком.Да и скрипт нужно подключать: jquery.unobtrusive-validation.js

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик да, скрипт похоже не тот взял, но тем не менее раз у вас это не работает, значит что-то где-то не доподключили, или подключили не так. Да и C# вам не будет делать клиентскую валидацию как писали ребята выше, он только серверной занимается. Клиентская же кастомная делается через атрибут Remote.

Comment: хм, я уже несколько раз читал эту статью, странно, что не заметил этот раздел

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Jquery validation (из статьи )
[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/Тут](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%82) можете посмотреть, на самом деле, есть много библиотек для данной цели.

Comment: А смысл?C# выполняет ту же работу

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик Данный плагин всего лишь на фронте выводит правила по атрибутах, которые заданы в коде (c#) – Міша прямо сейчас   править

Comment: Міша, так в Nuget пакетах такая библиотека есть, и с помощью нее  выполняется клиентская валидация